# How to store data for a user across servers discord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I couldn't find any answers that helped me anywhere so I guess i'll ask it myself.

How do you store data for one user across servers? Example: If server A has a bot and the user enters their favorite number or something, how can the same bot on server B print that number? (Assuming the user is on both servers). And does it work the same way with DM's with the bot? What about multiple users?

I really have no clue what class or variable you use for this, so I haven't tried anything myself.

Comment: The client's event, `message` is listening for messages from all servers your bot is in.
You can use `message.guild` to get the `Guild`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some code to accept the commands `!favNum` and `!favColor`. If no arguments are passed, the bot will attempt to retrieve the saved value; if an argument is passed, the bot will save that value.

The message event handler listens for messages on all servers, as stated by [Jakye in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63240620/how-to-store-data-for-a-user-across-servers-discord/63245345#comment111829045_63240620):

> The client's event, `message` is listening for messages from all servers your bot is in. You can use `message.guild` to get the `Guild`.

**Warning: the following code will lose all data if the bot restarts.**

```js
// Set a prefix for commands
const prefix = '!';

// Create a collection for all data
const data = new Discord.Collection();
// Create individual collections for different pieces of data
data.set('favNum', new Discord.Collection());
data.set('favColor', new Discord.Collection());

client.on('message', message => {
  // Exit if the message was sent by a bot or doesn't start with the command prefix
  if (message.author.bot || !message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  // Split the message into a command and arguments
  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  // Execute a section of code depending on what the command was
  switch (command) {
    // Favourite number command
    case 'favNum':
      // If no arguments were passed, try to get the saved value
      if (!args[0]) {
        if (!data.get('favNum').has(message.author.id)) return message.reply(`you haven't set a favorite number.`);

        const favNum = data.get('favNum').get(message.author.id);
        message.reply(`your favorite number is ${favNum}.`);
      }

      // If arguments were passed, set the value
      data.get('favNum').set(message.author.id, args[0]);
      break;

    // Favourite color command
    case 'favColor':
      // If no arguments were passed, try to get the saved value
      if (!data.get('favColor').has(message.author.id)) return message.reply(`you haven't set a favorite color.`);

        const favColor = data.get('favColor').get(message.author.id);
        message.reply(`your favorite color is ${favColor}.`);
      }

      // If arguments were passed, set the value
      data.get('favColor').set(message.author.id, args[0]);
      break;

    // Default reply if the command was not recognized
    default:
      message.reply(`could not recognize the command \`command\`.`);
});
```

Comment: Will try this. I'm trying to host my bot first

Answer (score 0):

You can get the guild where the message came from with `message.guild` and the content of the message with `message.content`.

Now in your specific example, it should work with something like the following:

```
client.on("message", message => {
   const messageContent = message.content;
   const guildA = message.guild;
   const guildB = client.guilds.cache.get("the id of guild B"); //you can get this with guild.id
   
   //Now we just need to get the channel where the message in guild B should appear
   //This would be one way of doing it:
   const channel = guildB.channels.cache.get("the id of some channel of guildB");

   channel.send(messageContent);
}
```

Comment: Getting the channel id and the `guildB` id would be easier if the user enters a command in that channel, which is what i'm planning to do.

Comment: But what about multiple users where each user needs a `message.content` variable? How would you automatically create one with the user ID? And how many users would be too much for the bot to handle the variables?

Comment: Of course, it would be easier to do it with a command and not hard-code it, as I did. But the question was about the objects and properties in discord.js and not about how to build the command.

Comment: If you want to do it with a DM it gets a little bit more complicated. You can find the user you want to receive the message with `client.users.cache.get("userID");`
  
Bots need to have at least 1 common server with a user to be able to send a direct message. So make sure your bot is in the user's server.

Comment: I don't get what you're planning to do. So you are trying to build command with the user and the channel ID from the other channel as parameters?